# Can not import my project

Tags: android, import

I bought an app source from codecanyon. The developer said these packages must be installed on Android Studio:
Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK Build-tools, Android Support Repository, Android Support Library and Google Play services

I have all of them.(right?)
[image: http://8pic.ir/images/c4ytp78k20l3o3wth5j1.jpg]

But I can not import that project. See this image please:
[image: http://8pic.ir/images/dhvyhs9dpr8wu662hect.jpg]

Can you help me to import this project?

Comment: later i have a similar problem. i think its a bug of android studio. i solved it simply by using another version of as;)

Comment: Try opening the project, not importing it. In Android Studio an import changes the project to a Gradle based project. If the project is already in that format all you have to do is open it.

Comment: But your problem is the sdk. Which is not working. So might need to reinstall or fix the sdk manager

Comment: It looks like you only need to install SDK platfrom 22.

Answer (score 0):

Open the sdk manager from Android Studio (instead of clicking on the link). Then check whether you have the API installed or not.

UPDATE: I didnt check your first screenshot, you need to click Select New in the sdk manager to load the not installed sdk api versions.

Comment: You mean click on: select new or updates
I click on new but anythings shows